# Não consigo centralizar a imagem!

Tags: html, css

Como eu centralizo uma **imagem** dentro de uma **DIV**? (*em html*)

Comment: use o display:flex align-items:center justify-content:center (para a imagem não vazar de dentro do elemento, pode-se colocar também um overflow:hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `<center>...</center>` ou colocar no CSS:

```
.minhaimg {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Se quiser ver mais: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.pt_BR.html

Comment: Etiqueta `<center>` é desaconselhada/não suportada em html5. [Referência](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)

Comment: obs. para margin auto funcionar o elemento tem que estar display block com largura definida